# Locking rows at the last minute

Tags: apex, locking

I have a utility routine (pasted below) that I use for all writes to the database which lets me catch errors.  This works perfectly in all but one of my orgs.  In that org, I generate a ton of UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors.  This is probably because it's a very complex org with lots of processes, many external, updating data.

The method receives a list of SObjects which it acts upon.

How would I go about re-querying the objects in the received list from this method using FOR UPDATE so I can quickly commit the changes while minimizing the lock time?

```
public static void saveList(string command, list<sobject> objList, string caller){
    if ( objList == null || objList.size() == 0 ) return;
    try {
        if (command == 'insert') insert objlist;
        else if (command == 'update') update objlist;
        else if (command == 'upsert') upsert objlist;
        else if (command == 'delete') delete objlist;
    } catch (exception e){
        logError(caller, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `FOR UPDATE` will not help you *avoid* lock contention - it explicitly establishes a lock. There is not a universal quick fix for high volume row-locking errors. It's very situation-dependent.

Comment: What if I get all of the object ids from objList, and query that same set of objects using FOR UPDATE.  Then loop through each record using getpopulatedfieldsasmap() to effectively reproduce the mods in the records I’ve received in the newly queried & locked records then saving them?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW error is situational. For example, two different users updating two different contacts on the same account might get this error, or two users might try to update the contact at the same time, or one might try to update the account while another is updating a contact. And that's just accounts and contacts. This can happen with contacts and opportunities and other combinations. Accounts especially tend to be pretty heavily used, and these are likely scenarios.

What FOR UPDATE gives you, though, is an approximately 5 second window for two transactions to lock gracefully. For example, in the two different contacts scenario, locking the account means that as long as one contact can complete the transaction and release the lock within five seconds, the other transaction will go through. However, with all of these various scenarios, plus the lack of communication regarding *which* record failed to acquire a lock, there really isn't a one-size-fits-all solution.

Whatever method is calling this method should attempt to get locks before calling this method. It'd be far too much overhead to make a method like this work in every possible scenario, as it would have to describe everything, check for non-null values, generate dynamic queries, all in the hopes that it catches every record it needs to lock. This would be incredibly inefficient and likely exceed governor limits for even modest-sized projects. It's great that you want to try and minimize code, but locking is one scenario that should always be custom-tailored to the logic.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to minimize locking issues is by minimizing the duration of the transaction. This is a challenge in Salesforce since you can't explicitly commit your transaction (see Idea below).

[Support explicit database commits](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IMz7)

Using FOR UPDATE will hold the locks **longer**, and you won't get the FOR UPDATE lock if the record is already locked by another process.

The way to reduce lock time in Salesforce is predominately by reducing the size of the transaction, typically done by pushing functionality to async processes, and as sfdcfox says, that's very situational.

You could attempt to reduce duration of the lock by using a Unit of Work pattern (fflib_Common attempts this), but that has its own challenges.